# configure odoo out and in going mail

Tags: smtp, config, odoo-11, outgoing-mail

I did config odoo out and in going mail and it successed . 
when I try send an email to user it doesnt recieve to the user email ?
Is there something else I have to do ?

I am using my cpanel smpt rom other domain.

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Check the 'Email' section underneath of 'Setting' menu, where you get all mail related matters.

Comment: thanks for repaly. but there is no error . is there other configartion to edit?

Comment: No there is no any other configuration needed but need to ask have do test run the outgoing as well as incoming mail server ?

Comment: I am using 2 domains in odoo one of them set to point vps lightsail + nginx. other domain used to config the outgoing mail odoo